# Android id's are all out of sync

Tags: android, layout, synchronization

In my layout I renamed all the controls from their defaults (all from Eclipse gui), however I noticed my R.java file didn't have the correct id constants so I ran a project clean and after saving, it re-generated it correctly*.

However, when I am trying to reference an id that exists, e.g. android:layout_alignLeft="@id/selectKey":

1. If I type it into the xml by hand I get 'resource not found' from the compiler despite it being in the R.java and being the actual name of the control that I gave it.
2. If I try and update the same property using Eclipse when I expand 'ID' from the dialog box it still contains a list of the original names only and not the new ones I gave it (and as named in the R.java file)

How can I fix this? It seems that something is not syncing correctly.

*btw, I don't know if this is a bug but after I cleaned the project it removed the R.java file but then refused to recreate the R.java because my code referenced the R object which didn't exist. In the end I had to comment out every reference to R in my code just so it would regenerate the R.java file. So it's a case of R being created relying on compiler succession yet compiler succession relying on R being there.

Comment: have you tried project > clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Project -> Clean does not work. You can delete the "gen" folder (the horror). Eclipse will then rebuild it for you.

Comment: Deleting gen folder worked, no idea what the difference between that and deleting R.java is, however thanks :)

However, how do you fix the issue of circular dependency on R.java is not created until all bugs are fixed and you cannot fix bugs until R.java is created (i.e. my code used R object so would not compile and I had to comment out every single line referencing R before R.java was created.

Comment: That's a good question on its own - the gen folder and it's contents will rebuild automatically BUT if there is a problem somewhere it effectively aborts the build. IF you fix the errors (E.g. XML layout error) then clean the project it should successfully rebuild, without the need to comment everything out. If you look on the error tab in Eclipse it will tell you the problems, and in my experience the one at the top of the list is normally your actual issue.

Comment: Thanks, all sorted now. My first killer android app is almost complete ;)

Comment: please post so we can see what we contributed to.

Comment: Turns out that the fault was the order of the items in the XML. How stupid is that? In the sample below, If the text box is defined before the button it fails.

                 <ToggleButton
                     android:id="@+id/toggleShowHidePhrase"
/>
            
                 <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/editPhrase"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/toggleShowHidePhrase"/>

Comment: OK. The reason it fails the other way around is to do with the fact that the order the views are defined is the order they are drawn. So if EditText is defined before ToggleButton the android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/toggleShowHidePhrase" will fail because there is no view drawn with that id. Looks good though.

Answer (score 0):

Manually delete the gen and bin or classes folder then try another clean.

Also, and it sounds like this is not the problem, but be sure that you are importing the right R in your code; i.e. your one, not the android.R one.